# VBA, calculation variance if cells's types are string or boolean

Tags: vba, excel, types, variance

How to skip cells with boolean or string in VBA, i need this part for counting variance, but if i run macros and a column has a cell with boolean it shows an error num 13

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim q As Integer
q = InputBox("Variance of which column do you need?")

Dim LastRow As Integer
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Dim sred As Long
sred = WorksheetFunction.Average(Range(Cells(1, q), Cells(LastRow, q)))

Dim s As Double
Dim s_2 As Double



For i = 1 To LastRow
s = (Cells(i, q).Value - sred) ^ 2
s_2 = s_2 + s
Next i

variance = (s_2 / (LastRow - 1))

MsgBox variance
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply check if the cell has a number

```
For i = 1 To LastRow
    If Cells(i, q).Value <> TRUE And Cells(i, q).Value <> FALSE And _
    IsNumeric(Cells(i, q).Value)) Then
        s = (Cells(i, q).Value - sred) ^ 2
        s_2 = s_2 + s
    End If
Next i
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can use `WorksheetFunction.VAR_S` to calculate the variance just as you did for the average:

```
variance = WorksheetFunction.VAR_S(Range(Cells(1, q), Cells(LastRow, q)))
```

Note that `VAR_S` and `VAR_P` differ in that the former divides by (n-1) while the second divides by n. `VAR_S` is the one that fits your code. You could also use `STDEV_S` or `STDEV_P` to get standard deviations. Also the sum `s_2` that you are computing in the loop is obtained with `DEVSQ`.

All the above functions automatically ignore in their calculation the non-numeric values in the target range.